# Need help figuring out what I did wrong in solving for equation of sphere (and finding radius/center).

Tags: vectors, spheres

I took a quiz in my vector calc class. I got a few points off, and am trying to figure out what I did wrong. Here's the question:

Show that the equation represents a sphere, and find its center and radius:
$3x^2 - 6x + 3y^2 - 3y + 3z^2 = 9$

For the radius, I got:
$R = \sqrt{5/4} = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 + z^2}$

And for the center I got:
$C=(1, 1/2, 0)$

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question to show us what you did (not just the wrong answer you got). Then we may be able to help. Until you do that you may get downvotes and votes to close. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work through it
and see what I get.

$\begin{array}\\
3x^2 - 6x + 3y^2 - 3y + 3z^2 = 9
\iff
&x^2 - 2x + y^2 - y + z^2 = 3\\
\iff
&x^2 - 2x+1 + y^2 - y+\frac14 + z^2 = 3+1+\frac14 = 17/4\\
&\qquad\text{You seem to have lost the 3 here}\\
\iff
&(x-1)^2+(y-1/2)^2 + z^2= 17/4\\
\end{array}
$

So center is at
$(1, 1/2, 0)$
and the radius is
$\sqrt{17}/2$.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Ugh, what a silly mistake. Thanks!